# 06 Kia Spectra EX lights

Tags: lights, kia

Reverse lights stay on when headlights are on. When lights are off they work, but the turn signal, and dash lights come on when I put the car in reverse. My driver side turn signal blinks fast like the bulb is out, but it's not. Left side works fine. The only fuse I remember having problems with was the lighter fuse, only twice, I have a fan plugged into it for summer time. help please thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 likely scenerios. One would be a bad headlight switch. Another would be a  positive short. This comes with 3 options. One you can get a wiring diagram and a multimeter and find where the fault is. Or you can try replacing the switch and hope it was the problem. This option can turn out to be expensive because you are guessing and to continue spending money on guessing gets pretty expensive. Or third you can take it to a shop that has a diagram, multimeter and the know how to use them and make repairs.

Comment: I do have a multimeter but I'm not very good at using it yet I need to read the rest of the instructions thank you for the help any suggestions I will take them and I'll get back to you and might need some help with the multimeter if you have time thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that there is an earthing fault or poor connection to earth on the right rear lamp assembly.

This is because putting it in reverse causes an issue with the right indicator.

Check the earth connections to the bulbs and the earthing points.

Comment: For earth, read ground or chassis as in battery negative connection. And poor connections can sometimes be seen on your multimeter as a voltage drop across the connection.

Comment: I did clean up a couple ground wires but I don't know they look pretty good to me,, but I cleaned them up anyway. Then I found a 30 a fuse in my fuse box under my hood. It did not go there nothing went there I took it out reverse lights are working exactly like they're supposed to now. But my turn signal still blinks real fast even though my bulbs are not out I'll take that. Thank you everybody